# Drawing a feynman diagram results in "unknown key"

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want to create something similar to this image (just the upper part, and with different line shapes):
[image]

with tikz, thus I started with defining the different elements and placing them:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    photon/.style={decorate, decoration={snake, dashed}, draw=red},
    electron/.style={draw=blue, postaction={decorate},
        decoration={markings,mark=at position .55 with {\arrow[draw=blue]{>}}}},
    phonon/.style={decorate, decoration={snake}, draw=green}
}
\draw(0, 0)
to[photon] (2, 0)
to[electron] (3, 1)
to[electron] (4, 0)
to[photon] (6, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Unfortunately that rises the error

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/decoration/\pgfkeyscurrent
```

for each line with a `to[]`. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can add decorations to segments of a path with `to`, only to the entire path. That is not to say you cannot use `to`, but you can't add the decoration as an option to `to`, it should be `\draw [<decoration options>] (a) to (b)`, not `\draw (a) to[<decoration options>] (b);`.

Also, the `dashed` option should not be part of the `decoration` options.

As a side note, I don't think the dashed line looks very good in this case, you could try `densely dashed`, or creating a custom dash pattern with e.g. `dash pattern=on 2 off 1` instead of `dashed`.

A working example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    photon/.style={decorate, decoration={snake},densely dashed, draw=red},
    electron/.style={draw=blue, postaction={decorate},
        decoration={markings,mark=at position .55 with {\arrow[draw=blue]{>}}}},
    phonon/.style={decorate, decoration={snake}, draw=green}
}
\draw [photon] (0, 0) -- (2, 0);
\draw [electron] (2,0) to[out=70,in=180] (3, 1);
\draw [electron] (3,1) to[out=0,in=110] (4, 0);
\draw [photon] (4,0) -- (6, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks! But now two additional problems: Where can I add `densely`? And what can I do to bend the electron lines?

Comment: @arc_lupus Just before `dashed`? I updated my answer, does that answer your questions?